# how to create Linphone Call parameter with this kind of address “3444”?

Tags: ios, iphone

```
LinphoneCall call = linphone_core_invite_address_with_params(<#LinphoneCore lc#>, <#const LinphoneAddress addr#>, <#const LinphoneCallParams params#>)
```

it throws me error like:

> belle-sip-warning-There is no object pool created in thread
>   [4564807680]. Use belle_sip_object_pool_push() to create one. Unowned
>   objects not unref'd will be leaked. 2016-08-14 01:20:45:856
>   belle-sip-error-header_address parser error for [3444] 2016-08-14
>   01:20:45:868 ortp-error-Cannot create LinphoneAddress, bad uri [3444]

I have tried with this code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Proper formatting of error

Comment: `3344` doesn't appear to be a valid Linphone address.